# What is the relationship with the variable user in Django with the User model?

Tags: django

I've noticed throughout my time studying Django that when I want to reference a users attributes I can do so by saying something like user.username etc. Obviously my assumption thus far has been that this variable "user" referencing the User model in Django but I haven't been able to find it anywhere officially. Can someone verify this to me so I can put this thought behind me?
Thank you!

Comment: Link to usermodel: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L389

Answer (score 0):

You can find the *default* [User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) provided by Django in (your python environment)

```
django.contrib.auth.models
```

otherwise you can customize your [User model like so](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Comment: The _default_ User model anyway, it's overridable.

Comment: Yes I know but since OP said ``referencing the User model in Django`` probably means he didn't customized his User, but thanks i'll edit my answer to add it